# Cannot edit or delete wordpress custom post types once published

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got a few custom post types running on my website and can't seem to make changes to them once they are published. I've been digging around on here and think it may have to do with `capability_type` and the associated permissions, but all of the answers I've looked at have either a) had no effect or b) removed my ability to access the posts at all. Here's the code in the functionality plugin that registers the post type:

```
function event_post_type() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                  => _x( 'Events', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'         => _x( 'Event', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'             => __( 'Events', 'text_domain' ),
    'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Event', 'text_domain' ),
    'archives'              => __( 'Event Archives', 'text_domain' ),
    'attributes'            => __( 'Event Attributes', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Event:', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'             => __( 'All Events', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Event', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
    'new_item'              => __( 'New Event', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Event', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'           => __( 'Update Event', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_item'             => __( 'View Event', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_items'            => __( 'View Events', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'          => __( 'Search Event', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
    'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
    'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'text_domain' ),
    'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'text_domain' ),
    'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'text_domain' ),
    'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into event', 'text_domain' ),
    'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this event', 'text_domain' ),
    'items_list'            => __( 'Events list', 'text_domain' ),
    'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Events list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
    'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter events list', 'text_domain' ),
);
$args = array(
    'label'                 => __( 'Event', 'text_domain' ),
    'description'           => __( 'Compositions, pieces, events!', 'text_domain' ),
    'labels'                => $labels,
    'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', ),
    'taxonomies'            => array( 'event_category', ' tags' ),
    'hierarchical'          => false,
    'public'                => true,
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_in_menu'          => true,
    'menu_position'         => 20,
    'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-calendar',
    'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
    'can_export'            => true,
    'has_archive'           => true,
    'exclude_from_search'   => true,
    'publicly_queryable'    => false,
    'capability_type'       => 'post',

);
register_post_type( 'event', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'event_post_type', 0 );
```

Many thanks for any ideas - still feeling very new at this!

Comment: Try going to Permalink Settings and save changes.

Comment: Thanks, didn't do it though

Comment: May be you need to add role compatibility manually.  Try adding this function also function add_event_caps() {
$role = get_role( 'administrator' );

$role->add_cap( 'edit_event' ); 
$role->add_cap( 'edit_events' ); 
$role->add_cap( 'edit_others_events' ); 
$role->add_cap( 'publish_events' ); 
$role->add_cap( 'read_event' ); 
$role->add_cap( 'read_private_events' ); 
$role->add_cap( 'delete_event' ); 
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_event_caps');

Comment: What is your user level on the site? Are there any role capability management type plugins installed like the Members plugin?

Comment: I'm an admin, and I don't have any capability-related plugins (or even users other than myself, ha).

Answer (score 0):

Check your functions.php for any additional code that might be registering the custom post type (e.g., with register_post_type).

Had a similar issue updating or removing a stubborn custom post type. Had overloooked some code registering the post type to add to search.

Answer (score -1):

**You may use this code**

```
//---Events Custom post type--
function create_post_type_events() {

    register_post_type( 'events',
    // CPT Options
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Events' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Event' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'events'),
            'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields' ),
        )
    );
}
// Hooking up our function to theme setup
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type_events' );
/*
* Creating a function to create our CPT
*/

function custom_post_type_events() {

// Set UI labels for Custom Post Type
    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Events', 'Post Type General Name', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Event', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Events', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Event', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All Events', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View Event', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Event', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Event', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update Event', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search Event', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'Not Found', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'twentythirteen' ),
    );

// Set other options for Custom Post Type

    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'events', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'description'         => __( 'Event news and reviews', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        // Features this CPT supports in Post Editor
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', ),
        // You can associate this CPT with a taxonomy or custom taxonomy. 
        /* A hierarchical CPT is like Pages and can have
        * Parent and child items. A non-hierarchical CPT
        * is like Posts.
        */  
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
    );
    // Registering your Custom Post Type
    register_post_type( 'events', $args );
}
```